# Volver draggable gráfica nvd3 con Angular o JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, css, drag-and-drop

Tengo un conjunto indeterminado de graficas nvd3 (digo indeterminado porque el usuario puede poner los que quiera) que se guardan en un vector

```
$scope.service.graphs.push(GraphsService.lineChart());
$scope.$apply();
```

luego uso el `ng-repeat` para mostrar los datos en pantalla

```
<div ng-repeat="graph in service.graphs" class="element_Graphics">
 <nvd3 options="graph.options" data="graph.data" ng-dblclick="setShowOptions(true, graph,$index)"></nvd3>
</div>
```

hasta hay todo me funciona a las mil maraviilas, el problema es que todos los gráficos me quedan en fila, 
[image: aqui se ven dos graficos en fila]

necesito que pueda arrastrar los graficos libremente por la pantalla y que se puedan organizar como quieran

¿Alguien sabe algo o como hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descargate la libreria jquery ui, alli existe una funcion como jquery, el cual tomas el id de este y lo haces draggable.

Adjunto el ejemplo que esta en la pagina jquery

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

La documentacion la puedes obtener de [aqui](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/).

Espero que sea de utilidad. Saludos!